# Как на macOS поменять версию PHP с 7.1 на 7.0?

Tags: php, macos

Через homebrew не получается даже установить 7.0

пишет:

```js
Error: No available formula with the name "php@7.0" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: В homebrew нету 7.0, есть только 7.1, 7.2 и 7.3. Зачем вам вдруг понадобилось 7.0, если существует 7.3?

Comment: @andreymal Для опенКарта 2, там 7.0 версия нужна

Comment: Согласно сведениям в интернете, opencart 2.3 должен нормально работать на php 7.1

Comment: @andreymal Да только там ошибка 
"Warning: mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!"

а mCrypt уже не входит в 7.1

Comment: mcrypt не входит в 7.2, а в 7.1 очень даже входит, его просто нужно включить

Comment: @andreymal В php.ini поставил extension=mcrypt.so и всё та же ошибка "Warning: mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!" у меня macos mojave. Второй день мучаюсь...